# Always On VPN on android does not reconnect

Tags: networking, vpn

I live in UK and recenlty I felt the need of getting VPN. Everywhere.

There is an option in android 6.x: Always-on VPN, but there are two issues with it:

- It does not reconnect after lost connection. That usually means that whenever connection drops for some reason you have to Unlock phone -> Go to Settings -> More connection settings -> VPN -> More -> Always-on VPN, change server you like to connect to, click OK and wait ~5s for it to recconect.
  Why wouldn't it reconnect automaticly (or maybe it doesn't do that only in certain situations)?
- In case server is not available I would like to be able to establish more than one VPN service, so phone tries first one, if it can't connect than go to second one, than third etc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem and have found it particularly annoying. I'm using PIA and their app just sits there unless I bounce the connection. I've just raised a ticket with them about it.

However, I suspect that this is more of an Android problem as I also see this behaviour when using OpenVPN. Specifically, when I drop the wifi connection and the phone switch over to the mobile data connection the OpenVPN client logs "write udp : network unreachable".

Looks to me like the VPN clients are binding to the current primary network interface and when that changes (by whatever means) they are not detecting that and switching to the new one.

I don't have a solution at the moment but I'll report back here once PIA respond to my ticket.

Comment: That not what I've observed. For me it seems to drop connection when I stay on the same WiFi network for extended periods of time (few hours). When changing media (from cellular to WiFi or switching WiFi) it usually wakes up and reconnects automatically.

Comment: Sounds like we may have a different problem although I have observed the behaviour you describe on my wired PC i.e. occasional VPN drops. They seemed to be much more pronounced when I had a TOR bridge running on another PC on my network.  

For other people having the "failure to reconnect on network change" problem that I described I have a workaround: switch to using TCP rather than UDP. The VPN client then detects the network change and reconnects automatically rather than just sitting there firing off UDP packets into the ether forever.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using OpenVPN with TCP to keep connection stable and more reliable. it also depends on the VPN service you are using. to understand why vpn fails you will need to take a look at the logs.

I don't think Android VPN natively offer always on feature, to get such functionality, you might have to use an automation service, like Tasker.

Comment: Android 6 has this functionality (some screen from the internet):
https://www.perfect-privacy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Android-Always-on-VPN-06.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I use PIA and downloaded their app from Google Play and it connects automatically. I have a Galaxy S5 and do not use the phone's VPN settings.